# Splitting text causing my arrays to become null

Tags: java, for-loop

The last `for` loop of my program isn't running. I have realised this is because the arrays are ending up as `null`, therefore it is skipping this part. I am not sure what I am doing wrong when splitting the text as this seems to be making everything go to `null`. Still unsure.

```
String[] splituptext;

for (int loop = 0; loop<temparray.length; loop++) {
    splituptext = temparray[loop].split(":");

    int score, min;
    try {
        score = Integer.parseInt(splituptext[1]);
        min = Integer.parseInt(splituptext[2]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return;
    }

    splituptext[0] = game[loop];
    score = scores[loop];
    min = mins[loop];
}

for (int x = 0; x < numofgames; x++) {
    System.out.println(playername);
    System.out.println(game[x]);
    System.out.println(scores[x]);
    System.out.println(mins[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the array like this:

```
  String[] splituptext = new String[some_lenght];

   for (int loop = 0; loop<temparray.length; loop++){
       splituptext[loop] = temparray[loop].split(":");
      ...
```

Try to change this wrong for loop:

```
 for (int x = 0; x >= numofgames; x++)
```

With:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < numofgames; x++)
```

Comment: Thanks, my three bottom printlines are still printing as null, 0 and 0. Have I made an error in my try catch?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in for loop is wrong, it should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numofgames; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your condition in second for loop evaluated false at the very beginning, cause `x>=numofgames`. Try this -

```
for (int x = 0; x < numofgames; x++)
```

A for loop continues as long as the condition part evaluated `true`

Comment: I just leave this here: [Are British/International English terms acceptable? (e.g. 'brackets' instead of 'parentheses')](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252503).